# What fields and calculation to use when trying to create a burndown chart from Azure Dev Ops into Power Bi

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi

I'm currently trying to create a burndown chart using data pulled through Azure DevOps into Power Bi using the Power Bi Connector.

The problem I'm having is that I can't find a field which contains the effort and amount of time a task took. The best I can find is adding a analysis view in Dev Ops and the field 'Remaining Work' however when a task is completed this field blanks.

Has anyone done this before, do they know what fields to use and what DAX(s) expression would be used to generate a burndown chart in PowerBi for Azure Dev ops?

Thanks for your help.